# Problem with Rigid Body Objects

Tags: animation, rigidbody

I've been trying to reproduce the treadmill (from this video at 1:45: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLRsCtd5P9s) and I've been going through a lot of problems with the physics and the rigid body objects especially.

I've got two main problems:

- First, when an object arrives at the end of the treadmill, it continues on the X axis instead of falling as it should do.
- Second, I also do not understand why but the object does not fall on the treadmill but instead it stops a bit before touching it. It still move in the good direction though.

Could everyone try to help ? I tried everything I saw to resolve the problem but I can't figure it out.

Here is the file if you need it :
[image]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: this way it won't work. You have to use an object (solidified plane e.g.), add array modifier and curve modifier. Then it can work, if you do the right things.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.  I already did that though. I created a cube that I shaped into a tile, then I added a curve and I added the array modifier and the curve modifier on my cube.

Answer (score 1):

1. tap "remove rigid body world"
2. then add it again

[image]

3. delete belt down (don't know why you have there 2 belts....)
4. change rigid body of belt like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Okay so, it did worked well, I did as you told me to with the difference that I switched the cube with a sphere. It still worked perfectly, so I decided to save and when I saved the sphere started to go through the treadmill again... I feel like blender is trying to mock me. I aslo feel like everytime I add a new object the rigid body world goes crazy. Do I need to add all objects before and then create the rigid body world? Anyway thanks for spending some of your time for helping!

Comment: "normally" no...but...rigid body has a cache. And that isn't that easy to delete....so....i don't know another way. In an easy setup you won't have to delete the cache at all for rigid body physics. I don't know why it is necessary in this case

Comment: please click on the checkmark left of my answer if it helped you. Thanks.